# Reducing third dimension of 3d tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tiff

I'm working on a land cover classification, and I'm testing pretrained models.
First I worked with RGB images jpg from EuroSAT dataset and I do not have a problem.
But, now I'm facing a problem with tif files, when I get the 13 bands' images.
I cannot feed them in pretrained models because of required input_shape dimension,
which is restricted to 3 channels when I have 13 channels. Are there ways to tackle this issue ?
An idea would have been to reduce dimension with pca, but tf.pca function only take 2D tensor as input. And in my case I want to reduce the third dimension, by passing from an input shape of (64, 64, 13) to (64, 64, 3). If you've got other ideas to tacke this problem they're very welcomed.

---

I split train and test according to a dataset
storing images' path and labels

```
ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df_train_strat['images_path'], df_train_strat["encoded_label"]))
ds_train = ds_train.map(lambda x, y : tf.py_function(parse_image, [x, y], [tf.float32, tf.int64]))
ds_train = ds_train.map(_fixup_shape)
ds_train = ds_train.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

ds_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df_test_strat['images_path'], df_test_strat["encoded_label"]))
ds_test = ds_test.map(lambda x, y : tf.py_function(parse_image, [x, y], [tf.float32, tf.int64]))
ds_test = ds_test.map(_fixup_shape)
ds_test = ds_test.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

and parse the images with the following function :

```
def parse_image(img_path: str, label: str):
    # Cast the Tensor to numpy and decode the string
    img_path = img_path.numpy().decode('utf-8')

    with rasterio.open(img_path) as src:
        img = src.read()
        # Channels last
        img = np.moveaxis(img, 0, 2)
        # Images normalization
        array_min, array_max = img.min(), img.max()
        img = (img - array_min)/(array_max - array_min)

    return img, label
```

Which gives me the tensors showed in My inputs 1 & 2

[My inputs 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RvwN.png)

[My inputs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhYaj.png)

Tensors'shape is (64,64,64,13) because I batched the images to 64

Then I simply call a pretrained model :

```
base_model = EfficientNetB0(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(64, 64, 3))
```

Unfortunately, I cannot adapt input_shape here, this will throw an error.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D())

model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))

model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax', kernel_initializer="glorot_normal"))

model.summary()
```

```
early_stop = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', mode = 'min',
            patience = 3, restore_best_weights = True, verbose = 1)

reduce_lr = callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_loss', mode = 'min',
            patience = 2, factor = 0.5, min_lr = 1e-06, verbose = 1)

    
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(ds_train, validation_data=ds_test, epochs=20, batch_size = 64,
                    callbacks=[reduce_lr, early_stop])
```

Then I fit it but Traceback is showed in links below.

[My outputs 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkMth.png)

[My outputs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX00i.png)

[whole traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixm7e.png)

Comment: Demonstrate by a simple, minified example if possible. input and output. That'll get your question answered much faster

Comment: Hello, I added pictures because I do not know how to display code blocks yet. Thank you. Shape is (64, 64, 64, 13) because I batched tf dataset by 64.

Comment: Use triple back ticks ``` to start a code block and ``` to end it. Most of the online programmer platform would use Markdown, so you should search code block in markdown on internet.

Comment: and by input and output, I meant a very simple example that anyone can replicate without the data you have.

Comment: By output, people won't probably mean Error, In python world they'll ask for *traceback*, so provide the whole *traceback*. Correctly given a simple tensor as input, what output tensor should be created, that example.

Comment: I edited it accordingly, thank you for your advices. Hope, it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As the question implies, you have a tensor of shape `(64, 64, 13)` the first two are width and height, and the last is the number of layers or bands in images; given to a model with predefined shape of input `(64, 64, 3)`.

You have two option:

1. Either perform slicing on the last dimension of tensor. Look at this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor_slicing.

   For your current example, you might already know what slices (bands of images) it might be important for the prediction task. Take those and ignore others.
2. As you said use PCA, and PCA does work for dimensions more than 2 as well, don't worry about it. You can bring down your data from 4,5,6 any dimension to whatever number less than what you begin with, but this also comes with a tradeoff.

You are relying on a Dimensionality reduction mechanism to bring down most useful features from a dataset. You might need to depend on another technique to determine how many features you really need, like [cumulative explained variance](https://wiki.adhadse.com/ml/mle-for-production/ml-modeling-pipeline/week2/?h=explained+variance#plot-the-explained-variance).

Option 2 is not what your model can accept, so option 1 is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try option 1 and dig deeper with pca.

Answer (score 0):

The images you are using might be [Sentinel-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel-2) images.

> Multi-spectral data with 13 bands in the visible, near infrared, and
> short wave infrared part of the spectrum

So you need to find out which bands out of those 13 bands come in the visible spectrum ie. RGB.
RGB bands are present at band index 3, 2, and 1 respectively(refer link for details), so you can get RGB images as follows:

```
#Get RGB image
rgb = img[[3,2,1]].transpose(1,2,0)
```

Overall the `parse_image` function to fetch the RGB image should look something like this:

```
    # Clip values which have very high pixel values
    img = np.clip(img/10000,0,1)
    
    # Get RGB channels
    rgb = img[[3,2,1]]

    #clip rgb values
    # For getting better images clip the range of pixel values for each channel. 
    # We take only the pixel values from 0 to 0.3 and scale them back to between 0 and 1
    rgb[0] = np.clip(rgb[0],0,0.3)/0.3
    rgb[1] = np.clip(rgb[1],0,0.3)/0.3
    rgb[2] = np.clip(rgb[2],0,0.3)/0.3

    rgb = rgb.transpose(1,2,0)
```

Comment: Hello, I had in mind this option to only keep the RGB bands, but I thought : why using multispectral if we stuck with the RGB bands. I thought it was a unfortunate to lose the information contained in the other bands. But in fact, I do not know if other bands outside visible spectrum are very helpful and informative.

Comment: You are right in your thoughts. But you also need to understand  that model needs data in visible spectrum as it is trained on data in visible bands. If you have domain knowledge on how to combine infrared and short wave infrared spectrum to visible spectrum and use that result as input for efficientdet model  then your thought process is in right direction.